# Return Excel file as result from MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, excel, model-view-controller, interop

1. If I opt for using Interop, does it require to have Excel installed on server-side?
2. Are there any additional reasons why not to use Interop?
3. Should I go for `System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView` server-side solution, populate it and write it in result?
4. Any other intelligent solution that preserves MVC logic and features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using interop will require Excel installed on the server side, and it's a bad idea to run Excel on your server. Per Microsoft itself: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support,
>   Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended,
>   non-interactive client application or component (including ASP,
>   ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable
>   behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

You can, however, create Excel workbooks server-side without using Excel interop. One solution to this is to use the [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) (free), which will create an Excel file, in a manner very different than interop. There are also some open source projects and commercial solutions which allow you to do this. Searching for "create Excel file server" on StackOverflow will give you plenty of options.

Comment: Thank you, will try with this SDK :)